# Runtime error 424 Object required VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this piece of code to calculate the yield using a formula for each of four given cases. However, I am getting an *object required* error and have been trying to solve it but in vain.

Initially I had the 'Options Explicit' on at the start of the code but I took it off, I tried changing the type of yieldProbe but it didn't help. I am relatively new to VBA, any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub getYield()

Dim siteProbe, binProbe As Variant
Dim yieldProbe As Variant
Dim SelectFolder As String
Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
Dim file_path, list_file, final_message As String
Dim csvFiles As Variant
Dim probe As Workbook
Dim probeSh As Worksheet
Dim lastRowProbe As Long

SelectFolder = GetFolder("c:\")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 'Check user did not cancel folder selection
If SelectFolder = "" Then
    MsgBox "No Folder Selected - Cannot continue", vbCritical
    End
End If

SelectFolder = SelectFolder & "\"
csvFiles = Dir(SelectFolder & "*.csv")
Do While csvFiles <> ""



    Set probe = Workbooks.Open(SelectFolder & csvFiles) 'will auto open
    Set probeSh = probe.ActiveSheet 'name of sheet ex probe sheet in probe workbook
    lastRowProbe = probeSh.Range("D10000").End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row of Probe Sheet
    Columns("Z:Z").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("Z1").Value = "Yield"

    For i_probe = lastRowProbe To 7 Step -1 'to loop through all Probe rows to obtain the HBin and Site Values
    siteProbe = probeSh.Cells(i_probe, 6).Value 'set site value of current wafer of probe sheet
    binProbe = probeSh.Cells(i_probe, 3) 'set bin value of current wafer of probe sheet
    yieldProbe = probeSh.Cells(i_probe, 26) 'set the yield value for the Z column


     Next i_probe

    Select Case siteProbe



    Case "1"

    yieldProbe = ((Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(binProbe, "1")) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(binProbe)) * 100

    Case "2"

   yieldProbe = ((Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(binProbe, "1")) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(binProbe)) * 100

    Case "3"

    ' error 424 here:
    yieldProbe = ((Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(binProbe, "1")) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(binProbe)) * 100

    Case "4"

    yieldProbe = ((Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(binProbe, "1")) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(binProbe)) * 100

    Case "5"

    yieldProbe = ((Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(binProbe, "1")) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(binProbe)) * 100

    End Select






    x = x + 1
    probe.Close True
    csvFiles = Dir

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "A total of " & CStr(x) & " files processed", vbInformation
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub



End Sub

Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String


Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select probe files"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: *Initially I had the 'Options Explicit' on at the start of the code but I took it off* - very, very bad move.

Comment: ^^ disclaimer: I manage that OSS VBE add-in project. FWIW its code inspections will highlight a number of common beginner traps, like that `Dim file_path, list_file, final_message As String` declaration you have here, which declares `final_message` as a `String`, and the other two as implicit `Variant`.

Comment: I've rolled back your answer-invalidating edit. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
binProbe = probeSh.Cells(i_probe, 3) 'set bin value of current wafer of probe sheet
```

Ignoring the fact that this (as well as `siteProbe` and `yieldProbe`) is getting overwritten at every new iteration of the loop it's in, I doubt any of these `Case` blocks works as you intend them to.

`binProbe` is declared as a `Variant`, but the way it's assigned, its content is going to be whatever the *value* of the cell is - that's a string, a date, a double, ...or an error.

Here's a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the exact error message and issue you're having:

```
Public Sub BlowUp()
    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CVErr(xlErrValue), "1")
End Sub
```

What does that mean? It means if you *probed* the value of `binProbe` in break/debug mode, you'd see that it contains an Excel cell error value, which can't be used with math: you're feeding your worksheet function with `#N/A` or `#VALUE!` or `#REF!` or whatever - it doesn't know what to do with it, and throws "Object Required" at you, because it's expecting to be given a `Range` (or an array), not an error value.

To give it a `Range`, declare `binProbe As Range`, and `Set` its value when you assign it:

```
Set binProbe = probeSh.Cells(i_probe, 3) 'set bin value of current wafer of probe sheet
```

Then before you use its value for anything, validate that it's not a cell error:

```
If IsError(binProbe.Value) Then
     ' can't use this value
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Corrected most of my 'beginner's mistakes' and edited the code. But you were right, it doesn't work as expected. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please don't change your question after you've received an answer that solves the problem you asked about, and read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513). Stack Overflow is a Q&A site that gives specific answers to specific questions useful to other people - it's not a "please help me debug my code" service. Learn to use your IDE's debugger. F9 to toggle breakpoints, F8 to step through; use the locals and immediate toolwindows.

Comment: I apologize. Was just desperate to figure it out. Thanks for the help though. Although I remember me not asking "can someone help?", I get where your frustration is coming from. I am learning a lot from this site and will make sure not to take unfair advantage and/or just use it as a debugging site. As for the debugging tools, I am using them breakpoints and step thru's to see the flow of code and the values of variables, but I wasn't able to get thru in spite of that. Anyways,....thanks. Won't happen again